# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, calendar

I am working on an application in which I have to create a `Lunar Calendar` 
I am creating a custom Lunar Calendar. There is very limited code on Lunar Calendar. But somehow I manage to create one.
This is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.wv);
         webView.loadUrl(contentUri);
       // webView.loadUrl("file://D:/Andro_WS_2/LunarCalendar/assets/calendar.html");

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                  

        webView.loadUrl("javascript:pushBtm('MU')");  
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:pushBtm('MD')"); 

        if(!ConfigCenter.getValue(this, Constant.KEY_WIDGET_ADDED, false)){ 
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

and when I run this code it crashes. My Error logcat shows:

```
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lunarcalendar/com.example.lunarcalendar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class net.youmi.android.AdView
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class net.youmi.android.AdView
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.example.lunarcalendar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  ... 11 more
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.youmi.android.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.example.lunarcalendar-2.apk
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
03-20 04:51:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  ... 21 more
```

and my XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:umadsdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.china.calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <net.youmi.android.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added the library for the ads in your project's libs folder ?

Comment: Post your manifest file code or check whether you have added the line `<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />` in your manifest ?

Comment: Yes Grishu, i have added the library.

Comment: wat is line 44 on MainActivity?

Comment: Line 44: setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Are you using your custom adview ?

Comment: post ur manifest code..

Comment: Are your sure you are using the Google Admob ?

Comment: No, m not using custom adview.

Comment: I have removed the AdView from my XML and Code and noe its working.I am fetching a HTML file from the Assets and when i run it my  avd shows "The webpage at (address of the file) might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
can someone please tell me why i am getting that error.??

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your adview class in your layout file.

Besides defining the adview as `net.youmi.android.AdView` try to define it like `com.google.ads.AdView` in your layout.

Add your `AdView` as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" <!-- Change this line also -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="your add id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```